# Working with Boolean in angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

I trying some hands on in angular. I tried using the same component for edit as well create product. I used an `if` statement in the component to distinguish between the edit and create. But the code inside `if` doesn't get executed when the request url is `http://localhost:4200/product/Edit/Redmond?edit=true`.  I have code to handle the route parameters. I removed it for brevity. I'm not sure what I'm missing here

```
export class ProductEditComponent implements OnInit {
isEdit= false;
uiProduct:ProductModel;
ngOnInit() {
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams=>{
  this.isEdit=queryParams['edit']      
  console.log(this.isEdit); // it's true here for the Edit Route
})
if (this.isEdit ==true) {      
  this.productService.
    GetProductByName(this.name)
    .subscribe((response: ProductModel) => {
      this.uiProduct = response;          
    });
}
}
```

Comment: You need to move the if logic inside this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe

Comment: You can access the parameters both directly and not async
But think carefully if it fits your case: this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams...

Answer (score 0):

`this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe` is an async function, so your `isEdit` recieves a value only after you check it. You could move their into the subscribe method or `await` the subscribe..

Comment: I moved the code of the ``if``` statement inside the subscribe but still the request for edit doesn't happen. And I don't know exactly how to await the subscribe

Comment: does it enter the if? I think you may be comparinh the string "true" to the boolean value true.. `try if(this.isEdit =="true")`

Answer (score 0):

The `isEdit` variable is assigned asynchronously. For inter dependent observables you could use RxJS higher order mapping operators (like `switchMap`) to map between them and `filter` operator to emit only if the `edit` parameter is true.

Try the following

```js
export class ProductEditComponent implements OnInit {
  uiProduct: ProductModel;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(
      filter((queryParams: any) => (!!queryParams['edit'])), // <-- proceed only if `edit` is true
      switchMap(_ => this.productService.GetProductByName(this.name))
    ).subscribe({
      next: (response: ProductModel) => {
        this.uiProduct = response;
      },
      error: (error: any) => {
        // handle error
      }
    });
  }
}
```

#### Update: use async query param elsewhere

Expanding from my comment, you need to maintain the async nature of the data to reuse it elsewhere in the code. You could use RxJS `ReplaySubject` with buffer 1. Also you need to make sure to close all open subscriptions when component is closed. I'm using `takeUntil` for it.

```js
import { ReplaySubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, filter, switchMap, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class ProductEditComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  uiProduct: ProductModel;
  editSrc = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
  edit$ = this.editSrc.asObservable();
  closed$ = new Subject<any>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(
      tap({ next: (queryParams: any) => { this.editSrc.next(queryParams['edit']) } }),
      filter((queryParams: any) => (!!queryParams['edit'])), // <-- proceed only if `edit` is true
      switchMap(_ => this.productService.GetProductByName(this.name))
    ).subscribe({
      next: (response: ProductModel) => {
        this.uiProduct = response;
      },
      error: (error: any) => {
        // handle error
      }
    });
  }

  someFunc() {
    this.edit$.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.closed$)
    ).subscribe({
      next: (edit) => {
        if (edit) {
          // do something
        } else {
          // do something else
        }
      }
    });
  }


  someOtherFunc() {
    this.edit$.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.closed$)
    ).subscribe({
      next: (edit) => {
        if (edit) {
          // do something
        } else {
          // do something else
        }
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.closed$.next();  // <-- close open subscriptions when component is closed
  }
}
```

Comment: This works but I'm not sure how could I extract the value of the ``edit`` query parameter if I have to utilize it somewhere down the code

Comment: @RaidaAdn: Short answer is you _cannot_. Atleast not synchronously like you were attempting. If you try to access it outside of the subscription, it may be `undefined` and there is no way to know when it'll be assigned the value. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921) to learn more about how asynchronous data works. Any statement that directly depends on the async data must be inside the subscription. Or you need to maintain the async nature using RxJS multicasts like `Subject` or `ReplaySubject`.

Comment: Understood the async nature. The link is very informational. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how the call to ``GetProductByName`` happens though the edit is false in case of create route ``/product/Create?edit=false``

Comment: Replace the `filter` with `filter((queryParams: any) => { console.log(queryParams['edit']); return (!!queryParams['edit']) })`. Now you can see in the browser console what exactly is the `edit` value.

Answer (score 0):

I like to create 2 routers, and load the same component:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
      { path: 'edit/:id', component: RequestReportComponent },
      { path: 'add', component: RequestReportComponent },
     ];
```

And in the component, check in this way:

```
isEditMode:boolean;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
             this.isEditMode = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
   
  }
```

Comment: I'm looking for the case where the queryParams would change.